# Append in Dom taking more time in IE than Firefox or any other browser

Tags: dom, internet-explorer, performance, append

I m working on .net framework 3.0 visual studio 08 and Testing it in IE8 and other browsers. Whenever I m inserting new elements in DOM (ex. 300 divs at one time) than I m getting the performance very slow in IE . Why?. If its a javascript debugging which is taking time or what else. Is it really true that IE Dom Append takes much time than any other browser. Please help me , I m stuck badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting large amounts of data can be very slow.

[This page details various methods of inserting content](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html).  I don't know much implementing these I'm afraid but it seems that some methods are 10x slower in IE7 than in Firefox.